# The problem of having a hard-to-read SHAP chart

Tags: matplotlib, machine-learning, regression, artificial-intelligence, shap

I plotted a SHAP chart for a dataset with six inputs and two outputs, 1000 observations. I also chose a Waterfall type SHAP chart.

The problem I got is that the dots appear on top of each other (vertically) as shown in the attached figure. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkT7n.png)
So I find it hard to interpret the effect of inputs on the outputs.

This is my code:

```
dataset = 
x = df.iloc[:, 0:6]
y = df.iloc[:, [6, 7]]
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
rf_model = RandomForestRegressor()
rf_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ('regressor', rf_model)
])
rf_pipeline.fit(x_train, y_train)

explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(rf_model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(x_test)

shap.summary_plot(shap_values[0], x_test)
plt.title('SHAP Values for Output 1')

shap.summary_plot(shap_values[1], x_test)
plt.title('SHAP Values for Output 2')
```

The problem is most likely related to the range of the data, because when the chart is drawn the x-axis starts from approximately -350 to 30. When I reduce the range, the points for the first variable (the one at the top) disappear.

Have any of you encountered such a problem before, and how did you solve it?

Comment: Will you try calculating Shap values on scaled (or at least demeaned) data?

Comment: I thought shap was supposed to be deviations from the mean, so unless the test dataset is significantly different from train, the shap values should all be roughly centered on zero?

Comment: You are (unnecessarly) scaling features in the pipeline and forget to apply it to `x_test` afterwards. Removing the scaling step will likely solve the asymmetry.